# how to insert json var into another json array in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

Could you please assist me to on how I can merge two json variables in bash to get the desired output mentioned below {without manually lopping over .data[] array} ? I tired `echo "${firstJsonoObj} ${SecondJsonoObj}" | jq -s add` but it didn't parse through the array.

```bash
firstJsonoObj='{"data" :[{"id": "123"},{"id": "124"}]}'

SecondJsonoObj='{"etag" :" 234324"}'
```

desired output

```json
{"data" :[{"id": "123", "etag" :" 234324"},{"id": "124", "etag" :" 234324"}]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to each `data` element using `+=`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

firstJsonoObj='{"data" :[{"id": "123"},{"id": "124"}]}'
SecondJsonoObj='{"etag" :" 234324"}'

jq -c ".data[] += $SecondJsonoObj" <<< "$firstJsonoObj"
```

Output:

```json
{"data":[{"id":"123","etag":" 234324"},{"id":"124","etag":" 234324"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use double quotes to inject data from shell into code. `jq` provides the `--arg` and `--argjson` options to do that safely:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

firstJsonoObj='{"data" :[{"id": "123"},{"id": "124"}]}'
SecondJsonoObj='{"etag" :" 234324"}'

jq --argjson x "$SecondJsonoObj" '.data[] += $x' <<< "$firstJsonoObj"
# or
jq --argjson a "$firstJsonoObj" --argjson b "$SecondJsonoObj" -n '$a | .data[] += $b'
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "etag": " 234324"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "etag": " 234324"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jq -s add` will not work because you want to add the second document to a deeper level within the first. Use `.data[] += input` (without `-s`), with `.` acessing the first and `ìnput` accessing the second input:

```bash
echo "${firstJsonoObj} ${SecondJsonoObj}" | jq '.data[] += input'
```

Or, as `bash` is tagged, use a Heredoc:

```bash
jq '.data[] += input' <<< "${firstJsonoObj} ${SecondJsonoObj}"
```

Output:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "etag": " 234324"
    },
    {
      "id": "124",
      "etag": " 234324"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uvXi1fCqAjK)